# Adding a constant to a $T$ distribution: does it preserve the sample variance and sample size?

Tags: statistics

Question is as stated:

> If $T_1$ follows a $T$ distribution with sample variance $s$ and sample size $n$ and $T_2 = T_1 +
>  k$, does $T_2$ follow a $T$ distribution with mean $\mathbb{E}[T_1] + k$ with sample
>   variance $s$ and sample size $n$?

This is not homework. Of course, it should be true that $\mathbb{E}[T_2] = \mathbb{E}[T_1] + k$, but I'm not sure if the variance and sample size are preserved in doing the transformation. One way I could approach this is to notice that $T_1 = T_2 - k$ and thus, 
$$f_{T_2}(t) = f_{T_1}(t-k)\left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}[t-k]\right| = f_{T_1}(t-k)$$
but let's see... although I have the pdf [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Definition), I don't see where the sample variance $s$ comes into play.

Comment: $\operatorname{var}(aX+b) = a^2\cdot \operatorname{var}(X)$ for all random variables for which $E[X^2]$ is finite.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - That's the population variance. Does it matter for the sample variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose one has an i.i.d sample of $\,n\,$ standard Normally distributed random variables, $\left\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\right\}$. The sampling distribution of the statistic 
$$
T=\dfrac{\bar{X}}{S/\sqrt{n}}
$$
follows a standard Student's t-distribution with $\,n-1\,$ degrees of freedom, where $\,\bar{X}\,$ is the sample mean and $\,S\,$ is the "*unbiased*" version of the  sample standard deviation. Note that, if $\,X_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\sigma\right)$ instead, then the sampling distribution of the statistic
$$
T{}={}\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} 
$$

can be shown to also follow a standard Student's t-distribution.

Now, analogous to how Normally distributed random variables can be written in terms of standard Normally distributed random variables, if $\,T_1\,$ follows a t-distribution with mean $\,\,\rho=\mathbb{E}\left[T_1\right],\,\,$ a scale parameter "$\,s\,$" and $n-1$ degrees of freedom, then
$$
T_1{}={}\rho  + sT
$$

where the constant $s$ is what, I assume, you refer to as the "sample standard deviation" and the degrees of freedom "$+1$" indicate the "sample size". [For more information, please see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Non-standardized_Student.27s_t-distribution). Consequently, for some constant $k$,

$$
T_2:=T_1{}+{}k{}={}\left(\rho+k\right){}+{} sT
$$
means that $T_2$ has the same scale "s" and degrees of freedom as $T_1$, but with mean $\rho{}+{}k$.